# Anime in which a man wields a gun loaded with different-coloured shells, each action scene is preceded by a pumping heart clip

Tags: story-identification, anime

So this is when I was still quite young so it might not be accurate.

The details I could vividly remember is this man's weapon, it is sort of a gun.
Before his epic action scene, there will always be a heart pumping scene and some mechanical stuff starts running.

He will load the gun with 3 different colour tubes (and starts describing them) into the gun and fire one very strong projectile to kill the enemy.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Maybe Outlaw Star? [Some of this lines up with Caster Shells](http://outlawstar.wikia.com/wiki/Caster_shells)

Comment: Hmm...is not Outlaw Star

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [*Final Fantasy: Unlimited*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_Unlimited), where the character Kaze wields the [Magun](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Magun), a gun capable of summoning monsters. Each time he fires it, the gun "unfolds" in a transformation sequence, then he picks three cartridges of colored "soil" whose signification he explains before firing the gun.

At various points in the sequence, the gun is shown to have a beating heart, which is shown beating faster in the last plan just before it fires.

There are a few examples of it being used in this YouTube clip:

Comment: Yes thank you very much. This is the one